# google apps script refactor repetitive code

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

What's a smarter way of doing this? Code works fine but is klunky.

```
function removeEmptyPending(){
  for(var row=2;row<=lastRow;row++){
    if( (tkhContact.getRange('A'+row+':A'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('C'+row+':C'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('D'+row+':D'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('E'+row+':E'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('F'+row+':F'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('G'+row+':G'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('H'+row+':H'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('I'+row+':I'+row).getValue() == "") && 
        (tkhContact.getRange('J'+row+':J'+row).getValue() == "") && 
        (tkhContact.getRange('K'+row+':K'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('L'+row+':L'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('M'+row+':M'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('N'+row+':N'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('O'+row+':O'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('P'+row+':P'+row).getValue() == "") &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('Q'+row+':Q'+row).getValue() == "") )
        {  
          tkhContact.deleteRow(row); // tkhContact.getRange('R'+row+':R'+row).setValue("");
        }
  }
}
```

I need to skip column B since there is a formula there so it's never really blank.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#is_Blank()`

```
function removeEmptyPending(){
  for(var row=lastRow;row>=2;row--){
    if( (tkhContact.getRange('A'+row+':A'+row).isBlank()) &&
        (tkhContact.getRange('C'+row+':Q'+row).isBlank()) &&
      ){  
          tkhContact.deleteRow(row);  //tkhContact.getRange('R'+row+':R'+row).setValue("");
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gets all the data from row 2 to the last row, including columns A through Q.  And then goes through the data.  So, it gets all the data in one operation.  The rows need to be deleted individually, and they must be deleted from the bottom up.  That means that the outer "for" loop must decrement the counter.  If you start deleting from the top down, then the row numbers from the last row deleted, change their row number.

```
function removeEmptyPending() {
  var data,i,j,L,L2,lastRow,row,thisRow,thisValue;

  data = tkhContact.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,17).getValues();//Get all the data from row 2 to the last row
  //including column A to column Q

  L = data.length;//The number of inner arrays in the outer array

  for (i=L;i>0,i--){//Loop through all the rows from last to row 2
    thisRow = data[i];//Get one inner array which is one row of data

    L2 = thisRow.length;

    for (j=0;j<L2,j++){//Loop through each element of the inner array which is the column value

      if (j === 1) {continue;} //Skip the second element which is column B

      thisValue = thisRow[j];//The value for this column

      if (thisValue) {continue;}//The value for this cell is not undefined null or empty string so continue

      tkhContact.deleteRow(i+2); // tkhContact.getRange('R'+row+':R'+row).setValue("");
    }
  }
}
```